# Is it possible to break out of a bash command which is executing based on a condition?

Tags: bash, memory-management

```
## 20141017
## run as a cron script every 5 minutes
## NB: Filesystem mounted on /u01 periodically exceeds 80%
##
#!/bin/bash

fs=u01

function deletion() {
        pushd ~ > /dev/null
        largedir=`du -k /u01 | sort -rn | head -n2 | awk '{print $2}' | grep -v "^/u01$"`
        echo $largedir
        rm -rf $largedir
        popd > /dev/null
}

usage=`df -h | awk '$1 ~/dev\/sdc1/' | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/%//g'`
while [ $usage -gt "40" ]
do
        echo "Filesystem $fs has currently reached $usage% usage."
        echo "Deleting files.."
        deletion
done
```

Let's say FS usage is 41%, and the size of `largedir` is 13G. If I allow deletion to run uninterrupted then FS usage will probably drop to 1%; When I run `deletion()` I would like the program to simultaneously check usage, and as soon as usage drops below 40% it must quit.
Is my approach right? Or would it be somehow easier to delete directories from smallest -> largest size via tail instead of head?

Comment: The `awk | awk` and `awk | grep` pipelines have a bad smell.  Remember that Awk is a superset of `grep` -- you can often refactor these to a single Awk script. `du -k /01 | sort -rn | awk '!/^\/u01$/ { print $2 } NR==2 { exit(0) }'` and `df -h | awk '$1 ~ /dev\/sdc1/ { sub(/%/, ""); print $5 }'`

Comment: Oh I didn't know that.. but is it bad to use different pattern matching mechanisms together as above?

Comment: Harder to read and maintain, and wasteful, so not really best practice; but on the other hand, whatever gets the job done without wasting lives is okay in the grand scheme of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your while loop, you may have to recalculate usage after running deletion.

If you don't want to delete an entire directory at once and risk putting you back down to 1%, then find/delete individual files and check if df is below 40% after each delete.

Otherwise, I think it might be ok.

Comment: No the problem is that once deletion() is run, it will delete the largest directory under the filesystem /u01, which is /u01/app. My question is - is there any way to _interrupt_ the deletion process while checking against FS usage?

Comment: Then don't delete entire directories - search for files in the /u01 directory and delete the files instead.  Use find to get the list of files, loop through the list of files and delete the file - after deleting the file, check if df is < 40%.  If df is below 40%, exit the loop. That might work instead. :)